# Android programmatically include layout (i.e. without XML)

Tags: java, android, include

So I've created an Activity subclass called CustomTitlebarActivity. Essentially, each main activity in my app will have a custom titlebar with many common features such as a Home button, a title, a search button, etc. In my current implementation, I am still explicitly using an include statement in the layout XML for each CustomTitlebarActivity:

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar" />
```

It seems natural that I should be able to do this within CustomTitlebarActivity. I have two questions: What code can replace this include tag, and where should I put the code? (My first instinct would be to put it in CustomTitlebarActivity's setContentView method.)

On a related note, I would appreciate insight into better ways to reuse android UI code (even if, per se, the titlebars need to vary slightly between activities.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Personally, I'd probably write my `Activity` subclass to always `setContentView` to a layout file containing a vertical `fill_parent` `LinearLayout` containing only my title bar:-

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/custom_titlebar_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <!--titlebar here-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I'd define an abstract `getContentAreaLayoutId()` method in `CustomTitlebarActivity` that returns the layout `ID` of the content below the titlebar for each subclass; the base `onCreate()` of `CustomTitlebarActivity` would then just call

```
setContentView(R.layout.custom_titlebar_activity_frame_from_above);
View.inflate(this, getContentAreaLayoutId(), findViewById(R.id.custom_titlebar_container));
```

Alternatively, you could have your abstract method for getting the content area return a `View` rather than an `int`, giving you more flexibility to construct your views dynamically (but forcing you to inflate them yourself in the simple *just dump this XML layout here* case).

Comment: This configuration did the trick, I'll experiment more with it. Any good ideas about how to allow a varying arrangement of action buttons onto this sort of titlebar?

Comment: That depends, but if there's a limited amount of fairly predictable customization (one or two custom button/actions) I'd probably stick with the "abstract method overridden by subclasses to get the image to use and action to take" thing (like an abstract getFirstActionImageResourceId(), onFirstActionClicked()) and just hook them in in the base class's onCreate().

Answer (score 67):

I met this issue too, and I just solved it now. I think my solution is easier:

1. create a inflater:

   ```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)      this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   ```
2. inflate the child layout:

   ```
   View childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child,
               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_id));
   ```
3. add it into parent:

   ```
   parentLayout.addView(childLayout);
   ```

It's done, enjoy it!

Comment: Precise answer for <include layout="@layout/titlebar" />

Comment: i think it should be `findViewById(R.id.child_id));` not `R.layout.child_id`

Comment: When I do this the widths dont seem to stay as defined in the layout. Dont know why

Comment: What's `R.id.child_id`?