# Android include tag

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

We can merge layout using include tag in xml

```
 <include android:id="@+id/all_tab" layout="@layout/all_tab"/>
```

How to add include tag from code?? Because i want to change it in run time. 
Thanks.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195668

Comment: did you reached your destination???

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_tab, null, true);
         
layoutContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutContent); layoutContent.addView(view);  It's working with this code.. Thx..