# adding a layout in another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

how to add one layout in another layout.I created this layout in tblrow.XML.so i want to add this rows in menu.XML.i want to add this rows depending upon the no of rows.How can i do that.If i add it how can i identify each row.Please help me.I need solution in java not in XML.
My Code is

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tblRowMovies" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/btn_backgrnd"  android:clickable="true" android:focusable = "true" android:layout_weight="1.0">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/movie" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="MOVIES" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textSize="20sp" android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>
```

.

Answer (score 27):

You can include one layout file in another and this technique is called reusing Android layouts using include tag.
e.g:

```
<include android:id="@+id/myid1" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
```

This is explained well in [a blogpost by Android developers.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html).

Yet another article on the [Android developer site explains the layout re-usability](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).

Comment: i know this.but need it in java code.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195668/android-programmatically-include-layout-i-e-without-xml

Answer (score 4):

Create file titlebar.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In main layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```