# android, how to load linearlayout from another .xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout

Say I have an .xml file with a menu that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/menubtm0"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/menubtm1" android:id="@+id/btm_fav" android:clickable="true"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/menubtm2" android:id="@+id/btm_search" android:clickable="true"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/menubtm3" android:id="@+id/btm_browse" android:clickable="true"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/menubtm4" android:id="@+id/btm_settings" android:clickable="true"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

What would be the best way to load it into another xml file?
For example into some FormLayout or something?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding a layout in another layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791822/adding-a-layout-in-another-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [Include](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) tag.